# Univocity CSV parser glues the whole line if it begins with quote "

Tags: java, csv, parsing, univocity

I'm using `univocity 2.7.5` to parse `csv` file. Till now it worked fine and parsed a row in `csv` file as String array with `n` elements, where n = number of columns in a row. But now i have a file, where rows start with quote `"` and the parser cannot handle it. It returns a row as String array with only one element which contains whole row data. I tried to remove that quote from `csv` file and it worked fine, but there are about 500,000 rows. What should i do to make it work?

Here is the sample line from my file **(it has quotes in source file too)**:

```
 "100926653937,Kasym Amina,620414400630,Marzhan Erbolova,""Kazakhstan, Almaty, 66, 3"",87029845662"
```

And here's my code:

```
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setDelimiterDetectionEnabled(true);
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> rows = parser.parseAll(csvFile);
```

Comment: Could you add a sample line from your file ?

Comment: @Arnaud yes, sure. Check the edit.

Comment: Do you have any way to change how the csv file is generated ?

Comment: @Arnaud no, i don't generate it by myself, unfortunately.

Comment: Double quotes are commonly used to escape text with delimiters in CSV, thus if your line looks like one entry that contains delimiters. I assume that `"Kazakhstan, Almaty, 66, 3"` would be an actual escaped entry and whoever wrote the line escaped it again and thus you get the escaped escape characters (i.e. double double quotes, `""`). The problem with removing the double quotes at the start and the end of the line would not take care of the incorrectly escaped double quotes in the line itself.

Comment: the csv parser is parsing the line correctly; solutions `Fix the program` that creates the file or write a program to fix the file

Answer (score 2):

Author of the library here. The input you have there is a well-formed CSV, with a single value consisting of:

`100926653937,Kasym Amina,620414400630,Marzhan Erbolova,"Kazakhstan, Almaty, 66, 3",87029845662`

If that row appeared in the middle of your input, I suppose your input has unescaped quotes (somewhere before you got to that line). Try playing with the unescaped quote handling setting:

For example, this might work:

`settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE);`

If nothing works, and all your lines look like the one you posted, then you can parse the input twice (which is shitty and slow but will work):

```
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
parser.beginParsing(csvFile);

List<String[]> out = new ArrayList<>();
String[] row;
while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
    //got a row with unexpected length?
    if(row.length == 1){
        //break it down again.
        row = parser.parseLine(row[0]);
    }
    out.add(row);
}
```

Hope this helps.